# How to add rows with values already predefined?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

In Oracle APEX I have a tabular form that returns one row and has cancel, delete, submit, and add row buttons. When I click the add row button it adds an empty row to the form but I would like it to add a new row with certain columns already filled in containing the same data as the first row. I was thinking I'd have to add a PL/SQL process to the page. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the default value for each column in the report to be based on the value of a hidden item (a hidden item per column) and set the values of these hidden items in a page load process by running the same query that populates the first row of the report.